# Can't start a new 50-pt bounty after already awarding a 50-pt bounty

Tags: support

I started a 50pt bounty on

> [Safari causing unexpected div offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029944/safari-causing-unexpected-div-offset#)

and awarded it an early answer that looked reasonable, but turned out to not work for me.  Then someone else submitted an answer that did work. I'm not trying to get back the first 50 points I awarded but I would like to start a second 50 point bounty for the question and award it to the correct answer. But when I try to start a second bounty the only award values offered in the drop down are 200, 250, and 300. I just want a 50pt bounty.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you won't be able to offer another 50 rep bounty.

According to the [bounty system FAQ on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067):

> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will
>   have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first
>   bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same
>   question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200
>   and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you
>   can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as
>   you like (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only
>   to bounties by the same user on the same question.

Each subsequent new bounty must be at least twice the previous amount, up to 500, which is the maximum.